# Identify nodes with 2 or more relationships with Cypher Neo47

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 200 User Nodes and 475 Location Nodes which I have created a relationship (VISITED) for each user who has visited any location. What I'm wanting to Graph all nodes where any location has 2 or more users who have visited that place.

This is what i have so far.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "http://x.x.x.x/users.csv" AS csvLine
MERGE (u:User {id: toInt(csvLine.user_id), name: toLower(csvLine.name), user_id: csvLine.user_id, user_type:'visitor'})

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "http://x.x.x.x/locations.csv" AS csvLine
MERGE (l:Location {id: toInt(csvLine.location_id), name: csvLine.location_name, location_id: csvLine.location_id})

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "http://x.x.x.x/visits.csv" AS csvLine
MATCH (l:Location {location_id: csvLine.location_id})
MATCH (u:User {user_id: csvLine.user_id})
MERGE (u)-[:VISITED]->(l)
```

EDIT:
Using the following i am now able to display all the Location nodes which have 2 or more visitors, however its not showing the user nodes. I have to click on the other nodes manually

```
MATCH ()-[r]->(n)
 WITH n, count(r) as rel_cnt
 WHERE rel_cnt > 1
 RETURN n;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some sample data:

```
MERGE (u1: User { id: 1 })
MERGE (u2: User { id: 2 })
MERGE (castle: Location { name: 'Castle' })
MERGE (pub: Location { name: 'Pub' })
MERGE (lake: Location { name: 'Lake' })
MERGE (u1)-[:VISITED]->(castle)
MERGE (u1)-[:VISITED]->(pub)
MERGE (u2)-[:VISITED]->(pub)
MERGE (u2)-[:VISITED]->(lake)
```

[image]

We then amend the query to return users connected to locations where the location has at least 2 incoming `:VISITED` edges from User nodes

```
MATCH (u: User)-[r:VISITED]->(l: Location)
 WHERE size((:User)-[:VISITED]->(l)) >= 2
 RETURN u, l;
```

[image]